# CSS Issue in Firefox/IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm working on a site's CSS and am running across an issue with the body margin section.  If you look at this in Firefox and then IE, you can see the line isn't lined up right in Firefox, but it is in IE. (In the black header section).

Here is what I have for the body tag, It's something with the margin and I can't figure it out:

```
body {
    margin: -2px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #E7E7E7 url(images/bg01.jpg) repeat-x left top;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #888888;
}
```

Thank you for any responses!

Comment: Well we can't actually see the effect ...

Comment: Because bg01.jpg is a local file. If you could put that image on imgur.com and provide a link, then it would be possible.

Comment: Ooops, I'm sorry, here is the link:
http://nickelsonassociates.com/new/

Comment: Do you mean you have a gap at the top? Either provide a minimal working example or a link showing the issue...

Comment: What versions of Firefox and IE are you testing in?

Comment: I see no difference FF 3.6 and IE8

Comment: The difference is only a couple of pixels on the top header (only displaying different in IE.).

Comment: Actually for me it looks fine in Firefox, but wrong in IE8. In IE8, there is a "notch" along the black edge at the bottom of the header; it's like a single stairstep down, and then another stairstep on the right side of the content column.

Comment: Yes Pointy, that's what I'm looking at too. Can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Why not just take out margin: -2px -- isn't that the problem?

Comment: I did take the margin out. When I took that out, it screws up FF.

Comment: or maybe try something like margin: -2px 0px 0px 0px;

Comment: @bethhilson so you *want* that stairstep effect?  The question makes it seem like it's Firefox that has the problem; I had assumed that the stairstep was the problem.

Comment: in any case, it looks much nicer than the old site.

Comment: It appears you built this page using some sort of Slicing export from photoshop. You are using way more background images than you actually need. Reducing those will help with a pixel here, vs. a pixel there issues between browsers. All that said, why is there a -2px margin on your body tag?

Comment: Wait a sec - the current style for the `<body>` tag (like, on the actual site) has the margin set to zero.  That makes it work in Firefox - without that, Firefox has a much bigger "stairstep" than IE does (with margin 0).

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset sheet?  Almost impossible to get anything to look the same cross browser without one of those.

Comment: @pointy - I do not want the stairstep in either FF or IE.

Comment: @beth I like the stairstep -- much more interesting than a plain header stripe.

Comment: Did this: *{margin:0;padding:0;}
It worked.  Thanks for all of your responses!

Comment: As you didn't mark my answer as accepted, did you actually pay attention to my answer? The "reset style" `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` is actually a **sledgehammer** which also "fixs" the padding of the `td` element which is the *actual* little bug here.

Answer (score 7):

You've placed the image with the text "Nickelson Associates" inside a table cell with a default padding which is 1px in MSIE. You need to force the `td` element in question to have a `padding` of `0`.

That said, using tables for layout/positioning is considered [bad practice](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/practicalcss/).